# I can't access content of object when send email

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5

I want to send an email in my Laravel 5.8 instance. I create a mail file and a blade and then pass the message as an object to my mail. When I send an email with all objects, the email is sent successfully. However, when I try to access the attribute from the object, the email is not sent.

**Controller**

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
   $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'name' => 'required',
        'message' => 'required',
        'phone_number' => 'required'
    ]);

    $message = new ContactUs;
    $message->name = $request->name;
    $message->email = $request->email;
    $message->message = $request->message;
    $message->phone_number = $request->phone_number;

    if ($message->save()) {
        \Mail::to('ahmed_ali_1994@hotmail.com')->send(new TestMail($message));
        Session::flash('message_sent', '');

        return back();
    }
}
```

**Mail**

```
public $test ;
public function __construct(ContactUs $test)
{
    $this->test = $test;
}

public function build()
{   
    $test = $this->test;

    return $this->view('emails.test',compact("test"));
}
```

**Blade**

```
<h1>Welcome</h1><div>{{$test}}</div>
```

[image: and this is result send it when sending all object]

Comment: Can you show us which attribute you attempt to access, and the code you use to do so?

Comment: i want to access all data from message object like name , email and phone number